# Xpages context.getUrl() in Notes Client ignores Back slashed "/"

Tags: url, xpages, ssjs

I have a xpages in which I am fetching the current URL using SSJS and trying to modify it.

```
var url:XSPUrl = context.getUrl();
```

url returns in browser is *http://servername/abc/database.nsf*.

but in Notes Client the url returns *http://servername!!abcdatabase.nsf*.

**Note: if I see URL manually the URL looks like *http://servername!!abc%5Cdatabase.nsf** ,

It means the "/" is encoded with "%5C",but after return from var url it just ignors encode string in it.

Is it some about escape characters? OR about encode or decode of URL.

Comment: Didi you "print" that somewhere? In computedText control for example? Maybe the way you look at it ignores that escape backslash.

Comment: Yes i have printed it and also make some alerts in different patterns